# How would I solve the following matrix problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&3\\ -2&6\end{pmatrix}

Find two 2x2 matrices B and C such that AB=AC but B≠C.

I have tried to do some multiplication and manipulation with the numbers but I keep getting the wrong answer.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the range of $B-C$ should be contained in the null space of $A$.